# Why is there so much blank space after the footer?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sticky-footer

Easiest way to see the problem is on the site itself: http://marketsay.com/

I have the bottom area (in blue) that I want to be a sticky footer. I thought I had it working on my laptop, but now that I look at it on a wide screen monitor there is a ton of space underneath it.

I have run through the document and CSSand can't figure out why, can you see anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following on to what you already have:

```
#wrap {
    position:relative;
}

#inner {
    margin-bottom:142px;
}

.disclaimer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```